# Material UI - set color for SVG

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I use Material UI in ReactJS and have the following component to render an SVG:

```js
import React, { FunctionComponent } from "react";
import SvgIconMUI from "@material-ui/core/SvgIcon";
import { SvgIconProps } from "./types";
import { ReactComponent as HelloWorld } from "Icon/Sections/icon-flat.svg";
const SvgIcon: FunctionComponent<SvgIconProps> = ({
  slug,
  classes,
  svgIconViewBox = "0 0 96 96",
}) => {
  const SpecificSpartenIcon = HelloWorld;

  return (
    SpecificSpartenIcon && (
      <div className={classes.svgContainer}>
        <SvgIconMUI viewBox={svgIconViewBox} className={classes.svgIcon}>
          <SpecificSpartenIcon />
        </SvgIconMUI>
      </div>
    )
  );
};
export default SvgIcon;
```

**What I want to achieve: set another color for the SVG.**

What I have tried to change the color:

```js
import { makeStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core";

interface Props {
  colors: ExpertColor;
}

const svgIconViewBox = "0 0 96 96";
const selectedIconStyles = { fontSize: 30 };

const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, Props>((theme: Theme) => ({
  svgContainer: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",

    position: "relative",
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
    padding: 0,
    
    fill: "red !important;",
    color: "red !important;",
  },
  svgIcon: {
    position: "absolute",
    height: "55px",
    width: "55px",
    top: 0,
    
    fill: "red !important;",
    color: "red !important;",
  },
}));

export default { useStyles, svgIconViewBox, selectedIconStyles };
```

It does not work. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Please show the portion of your code that creates the CSS classes (`svgContainer` and/or `svgIcon`) that set the color. It is not necessary to specify `!important`.

Comment: I have provided it ? 

{
fill: 'red !important',
color: 'red !important'
}

Comment: That one line doesn’t define a css class, it just defines a css property . Please show the full code for defining the class.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I have updated my answer now :)

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong in the code that you've shown. Please reproduce your problem in a code sandbox. Here's a working example of specifying icon colors in various ways: https://codesandbox.io/s/icon-color-ibydc.